# Is a JSON wrapper an adapter?

Tags: design-patterns, adapter

Please let me illustrate with a simple example. Suppose we have a Weather object:

```
class Weather:

    def get_forecast(self, day, place):
        forecast = "code that calculates forecast"
        return forecast
```

On the other end we've got a weather forecast web app that accesses the `Weather.get_forecast` method **directly** and renders the output on the browser.

However, if I create a JSON RESTFUL wrapper which accesses the Weather.get_forecast method and serves the output as a JSON string, that means I can then make requests to the JSON RESTFUL layer from my web app instead of accessing the `Weather.get_forecast` method directly, which is good for decoupling I suppose.

And my question is: is this JSON RESTFUL wrapper what is referred to as an adapter in software design patterns? To put it in another way, am I using the adapter design pattern here?

Comment: "which is good for decoupling I suppose"

Doing the same thing with an ethernet cable in between doesn't _really_ make it any more or less coupled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of kinds of "wrapper" patterns, and I wouldn't object to calling what you are doing an "adapter". However...

I think of an adapter more as a wrapper that allows use of an interface that the consumer couldn't normally use. In other words, my consuming class would like to make use of a service, but it can't do so directly, so I make an adapter that can, and consume the adapter instead.

I don't see this as your situation. You could call the get_forecast directly if you want to, but you don't want to.

Instead, I would describe what you are doing as a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). You are hiding the ugly details of the Weather service behind a pretty JSON facade.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. If I also create a TerminalFacade class that accesses the Weather object and serves its data through the command line using `input()` and `print()` would that also be the case of a Facade?

Comment: any idea about my question in the comment above?