# Is this code a wrapper or an adapter?

Tags: design-patterns

I´m using a framework for javascript to display beautiful alert boxes. This framework uses another framework to actually display the boxes. So it´s something like that:

```
 let showAlert = function (type, message, title) {
    opts = {};
    opts.title = title;
    opts.type = type;
    opts.confirmButtonText = 'Confirm';
    opts.text = message;

    return swal(opts); // here it uses the concrete component sweet alert
};

messageFramework.success = function (message, title) {
    return showAlert ('success', message, title);
};

messageFramework.error = function (message, title) {
    return showAlert ('error', message, title);
};
```

So the client uses the `messageFramework` abstraction, but the `messageFramework` uses the `swal` function of the sweet alert implementation. The message framework is a wrapper or an adapter?

Thanks.

Comment: see also: [Is a JSON wrapper an adapter?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/385705/is-a-json-wrapper-an-adapter)

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper can stand for several types of [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns):

- Adapter allows classes with incompatible interfaces to work together by wrapping its own interface around that of an already existing class.
- Decorator dynamically adds/overrides behaviour in an existing method of an object.
- Facade provides a simplified interface to a large body of code.

Of these, I feel like Facade best fits what this is doing, with Adapter being second best but also fitting.

Comment: I dont think it´s an adapter because it `wraps` other framework, it´s coupled by using the sweet alert concrete imp.